# How to enable gzip on my node server using connect?

Tags: node.js, gzip, node.js-connect

I am trying to have my node server gzip the responses that it gives. I have the following:

```
const connect = require('connect');
const formDataRequests = ['communities/upsert'];
const app = connect();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
...
```

I did some research (example https://alligator.io/nodejs/compression/ ) but that requires and express app. Does anyone know what module I can import/etc to get this to gzip the responses?

Comment: did you try at least? expressJs is bassed on `http` server as well, and the library you're using also supports middleware written exactly as expressJs middleware... give it a try on a simple route, check the data size with and without that... and see if it works  and BTW, you no need to include `bodyParser` just replace that with the `express` variable, like `app.use(express.json())` as express now includes bodyParser library 

Comment: Hi @balexandre , did you meant to do `app.use(compression())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [connect docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect), you can use the same compression middleware:

```
const compression = require('compression');
app.use(compression());
```

Comment: This middleware is not working for me. I have tried all parameters which help in compression but still not working.

Comment: @HardikPatel are you using connect or express middleware? How are you testing to see if it works or not?

Comment: I am using express.
Does compression has any problem with express.
I did the same thing in my another system with same config and it is working. why is this happens ?
Still I am facing problem in my main system.

Answer (score 0):

Use compression middleware

```
const compression = require('compression');
app.use(compression());
```

For serving, node gzip compression file use

```
app.get('*.js', function (req, res, next) {
    req.url = req.url + '.gz';
    res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
    // console.log('sent')
    next();
});
app.get('*.css', function (req, res, next) {
    req.url = req.url + '.gz';
    res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/css');
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @jcragun . We were able to get it working with:

```
const compression = require('compression');
app.use(compression());
```